# when calling database in python How to say if height is repeated First print row that has the smaller weight?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-studio

when calling database in python How to say if weight is repeated First print row that has the smaller height?

I have a query for a database like below:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM information WHERE ORDER BY height DESC;'
```

for example, my data is below:

```
name             weight              height
--------------------------------------------
row 0              125                  220
row 1              93                   185   <----- ( row 1)    
row 2              80                   185   <----- ( row 2)
row 3              66                   168    
row 4              91                   165
```

I want this:

```
name             weight              height
--------------------------------------------
row 0              125                  220   
row 2              80                   185  <----- ( row 2)    
row 1              93                   185  <----- ( row 1)
row 3              66                   168
row 4              91                   165
```

please help me thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this question has nothing to do with Python, but rather with the SQL.

If I understand you correctly, you want your output to be ordered by `height` in descending order, but if the `height` parameter is the same, then ordered by `weight` in ascending order.

The below Query should do the job:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information
ORDER BY height DESC, weight ASC
```